# How does one compute/create a concrete/actual string in coq to pass to functions or store in a variable/identifier?

Tags: coq

I simply want to create a concrete string and do stuff with it as if coq was a programming language. How do I create a string?

I tried:

```
(* From Coq Require Export String. *)
(* Compute "hello". *)
(* Require Import Ascii String. *)
(* Compute "hello". *)
(* Open Local Scope char_scope. *)
(* Compute "hello". *)
(* Example Space := " ". *)

Module Export StringSyntax.
End StringSyntax.

(* Example HelloWorld := " ""Hello world!"" ".
Compute "hello". *)

Print "hello".
```

which none work the way:

```
Compute 2.
```

displays:

```
     = 2
     : nat
```

How do I create an actual string or symbol so I can pass it to functions I create etc?

---

super hacky....but wish it was different:

```
Inductive my_parens : Type :=
| LeftMyParen
| RightMyParen.

Notation "<<<<" := LeftMyParen.
Notation ">>>>" := RightMyParen.
Compute LeftMyParen.
Compute RightMyParen.
```

out

```
     = <<
     : my_parens
     = <<<<
     : my_parens
     = >>>>
     : my_parens
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just had the scope wrong:

```
Require Import Coq.Strings.String.
Open Scope string_scope. (* NB *)
Compute "Hello, world!".
```

Comment: but when I copy paste the example from the docs it fails: https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Strings.String.html `Module Export StringSyntax.
End StringSyntax.

Example HelloWorld := " ""Hello world!"" ".`

Comment: btw, why are both import lines needed but not in the example from the docs?

Comment: why not:
`Require Import String. Example HI : string := "abc".`

Comment: I do not quite know what the `StringSyntax` module is doing there. But you need to have the `Open Scope` command _even_ if you import the `String` (or `Coq.Strings.String`) module. That is because that scope is only opened locally in the file.

Comment: I don't understand what the difference btw opening and importing is then :/ In python if I import things it works. I don't have to do more. Whats the difference?

Comment: Importing is for modules (defined with the `Module` keyword) or for compiled files. Opening is for notation scopes, which are only used by the Coq parser and printer to determine how to interpret Coq syntax.

Comment: @CharlieParker The documentation is extracted from the file String.v itself. In this file, you have `Local Open Scope string_scope`, meaning that string notations can be used by default. If you want to use them in another file, you need to open the scope, as explained by Arthur. Note that you can also open the scope locally with `Compute "Hello, world!"%string`.

Answer (score 0):

If your desperate from (finite) symbols you can do this:

```
Inductive my_parens : Type :=
| LeftMyParen
| RightMyParen.

Notation "<<<<" := LeftMyParen.
Notation ">>>>" := RightMyParen.
Compute LeftMyParen.
Compute RightMyParen.
```

out

```
     = <<
     : my_parens
     = <<<<
     : my_parens
     = >>>>
     : my_parens
```

Answer (score 0):

also works:

```
Require Import String.
Example HI : string := "abc".
```